# How to know the host address to connect to mysql in AWS EC2?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin, localhost, host

I installed phpmyadmin and created a database however to connect externally remotely using a node js script to connect to my database but I don't know what my database hostname is.

In phpmyadmin it just shows that it is localhost but to access off the machine I don't know what is the correct address could someone please help me with this?

I've already tried using my public ip but it doesn't connect to the database or it's not the right host.

Comment: Where is the database installed (e.g. Local PC, Amazon EC2 instance)? Where is the system trying to connect to it? You need to be sure that there is no firewall blocking access between the two, and that port-forwarding is enabled on any router that's using NAT.

Comment: What is the configuration of the Inbound Security Group on the instance?